# How to add a meta/comment to a sequence defined via def in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, metadata, function

I had to comment out the line below (example is from http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming/Examples/Lazy_Fibonacci)

```
(def fib-seq
  ;"Implements Fibonacci sequence (starts with 0)."
  ((fn rfib [a b] 
     (lazy-seq (cons a (rfib b (+ a b)))))
   0 1))
```

If I left it in, I would get:

```
Clojure 1.2.0
java.lang.Exception: Too many arguments to def (Problem1.clj:1)
1:1 user=>
```

I can do this with `defn`, however. Example (I know, I am reinventing the wheel for `even?` is already defined):

```
(defn is-even? [n]
  "Returns true if the number is even, false otherwise."
  (== (mod n 2) 0))


Clojure 1.2.0
1:1 user=> (is-even? 3)
false
1:2 user=> (is-even? 4)
true
1:3 user=>
```

Comment: You should mark MayDaniel's answer as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(def ^{:doc "Implements Fib. sequence lazily."} fibs ...)`

`(:doc (meta (var fibs)))`

`; "Implements Fib. sequence lazily."`

---

It's simple enough to write a macro so you could write `(def-with-docs foo "doc" 1)`.

```
(defmacro def-with-docs [name docstring value]
  `(def ~(with-meta name {:doc docstring}) ~value))

(def-with-docs fib-seq "Implements Fibbonaci sequence (starts with 0)."
  ((fn rfib [a b] (lazy-seq (cons a (rfib b (+ a b))))) 0 1))
```

`(:doc (meta (var fib-seq)))`

`; "Implements Fibbonaci sequence (starts with 0)."`

---

Also, note that with your example use of `defn`, the docstring should precede the arguments, else it won't be associated with the symbol's metadata.

---

Alternatively, one can use [clojure.contrib.def/defvar](http://clojure.github.com/clojure-contrib/def-api.html#clojure.contrib.def/defvar).

Comment: See clojure.contrib.def/defvar for an existing macro

Answer (score 4):

This issue is "fixed" already in the new alpha releases for Clojure 1.3, where def supports an optional docstring.

```
user> (clojure-version)
"1.3.0-alpha3"

user> (def answer "the answer to the final question" 42)
#'user/answer

user> (doc answer)
-------------------------
user/answer
nil
  the answer to the final question
nil
```

Comment: Thanks, when is this version projected to be stable?

Answer (score 0):

From http://clojure.org/special_forms#def

> (def symbol init?) creates and interns
>   or locates a global var with the name
>   of symbol and a namespace of the value
>   of the current namespace.

From http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/defn

> (defn name doc-string? attr-map?
>   [params*] body)
>   is the same as (def name (fn [params* ] exprs*)) with any doc-string or attrs added
>   to the var metadata.

So, when you write (def fib-seq "your comment" (...)), you are trying to define a symbol fib-seq with value "your comment", and clojure complains there are too many arguments.

Comment: Ok, so how do I add comment / documentation to it then?